# Solving invalid geometry in QGIS

Tags: geometry, gis, polygon, qgis

I came across this issue when trying to use *simplify* on a polygon layer.
*Simplify* stops because of invalid geometry ([Example of problem spots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LgT2.png)).

When I try to check the geometry using the available tool (*check validity*), the whole polygon gets labelled invalid, and the areas indicated in the picture ([Example of problem spots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LgT2.png)) are highlighted as errors.

I attempted to remove these areas by using *delete holes*, but this only fixes the errors inside the polygon and not those around the edges.

How can these be fixed in a methodical, automated way? I get hundreds of such errors along the edges of the polygon, and this process will eventually have to be repeated for hundreds of other shapefiles, so a manual approach is not feasible.

Background: I am using QGIS 3.2.3 - Bonn, and I have limited experience with the software and GIS in general. I did not generate the original polygons myself, so I don't have control over that unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix the errors in this case by using the *fix geometries* tool.